How to override exception class in custom module in odoo 13?
I was trying to override one of Odoo's exception classes in my custom module. Here is what i tried.
exception.py
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError, except_orm
from odoo.http import request
print('-------am here-------------')
class ValidationError(ValidationError):
    ​def __init__(self, msg):
    ​   ​print('print ValidationError------',msg)
    ​   ​super(ValidationError, self).__init__(msg)

But still, the validation error gets called from the base class, not my custom class.
